# jQuery append li can't be removed

Tags: jquery, html, append

I'm trying to add list items with links and when i'm trying to remove them nothing happens. But if i create the li items in my HTML they do get removed..

My append code-

```
fileInput.append('<li><span>' + fileurl + '</span><a><img src="/remove-slide.png" /></a></li>');
```

My remove code-

```
jQuery('li a').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

When i use the same append code as static HTML, i can remove it without a problem. But when i add these lines using append nothing happens.
How can i fix this please? :)

Comment: What happens if you do `.parent()` instead of `parent('li')`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation as you are adding the `li` element dynamically:

```
jQuery('body').on('click','li a'function() {
     jQuery(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and i learned new syntax :)